# Django's geojson serializer outputs coordinates in the wrong order

Tags: python, django, geojson, geodjango, django-serializer

I am using the geojson serializer of Django but it is not getting the coordinates in the right order (according to the [GeoJson spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions)). Instead of (easting, northing) I get (latitude, longitude) and when I display the map I obviously get the wrong positions, since the longitude is interpreted as latitude and latitude as longitude.

These are my original coordinates:

```
[(38.8976094, -77.0367349), (19.4348892, -99.1447678)]
```

This is the serializing code:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
serialize('geojson', Place.objects.all(),  
          geometry_field='location', fields=('name', ))
```

And this is what I get when I serialize:

```
u'{"type": "FeatureCollection",
 "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}, 
 "features": [{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [38.8976094, -77.0367349]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": "White House"}}, {"geometry": {"type": "Point", 
 "coordinates": [19.4348892, -99.1447678]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": "Palacio de Bellas Artes"}}]}'
```

I installed GDAL and everything else seems to be working OK. Am I assuming right that the serializer should pick the right coordinate order or do I must do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

You get longitude and latitude in your geojson output because you seem to have the default srid 4326 chosen for the location field in your Places model. The GeoJSON Serializer also use 4326 as the [default srid](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/) when used. Are you trying to transform the original latitude/longitude coordinates to a different coordinate system/srid than 4326/WGS84 (you seem to expect eastings and northings?) when serializing the coordinates? Please elaborate.

My initial suggestion is to try to implement the [django-geojson](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-geojson) app into your project. "*[D]jango-geojson is a collection of helpers to (de)serialize (Geo)Django objects into GeoJSON.*". I use it if I need to output correctly formatted geojson.

Comment: Thank you @cassius, I solved this problem storing my coordinates in the database as longitude, latitude instead of latitude, longitude, this way my GeoJSON output is now correct, but I will certainly follow your suggestion to implement django-geojson in my project, since I will need to serialize data from more than one model and the default GeoJSON serializer from Django does not seem to have such option.